# Is the $ \emptyset \subseteq\{\{\pi/4\}\} $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the $ \emptyset \subseteq \{\{\pi/4\}\}
$?

I believe this is true since the empty set is a subset of each set but the double brackets are throwing me off.

Comment: The double brackets mean that the only element of your set is itself a set. In any case you shouldn't even be reading what the contents are, and answer what you answered. However, please don't use symbols in the middle of a sentence, I find it a little bit awkward if not irritating.

Comment: If it helps you to think, Let $\{\pi/4\}=A$.  Then your question is rephrased as "Is $\emptyset\subseteq \{A\}$?"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the empty set is a subset of any set. Full stop. No confusion necessary, and you don't ever have to think about what $\{\{\pi/4\}\}$ means in order to get your answer.

That being said, thinking about what $\{\{\pi/4\}\}$ means is a nice exercise by itself, but unrelated to this problem. The phrase "a collection of subsets of the real numbers" (or "a family of subsets") is often used, although this specific collection is rather small, only containing one subset.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for all sets $A$, $\varnothing\subseteq A$. The sole element of the set you are looking at is itself a set, namely $\{\frac\pi4\}$.